# How do I get each number a user inputs as set of numbers in string with each number separated by a space?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

For example, the user enters "1 2 3 4", how do I extract those four numbers and put them into separate spots in an array?

I'm just a beginner so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

```
for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
    scanner.nextLine();
    tempScores[i] = scanner.nextLine();

    tempScores[i] = tempScores[i] + " ";
    tempNum = "";
    int scoreCount = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < tempScores[i].length(); a++) {
        System.out.println("Scorecount " + scoreCount + " a " + a );

        if (tempScores[i].charAt(a) != ' ') {
            tempNum = tempNum + tempScores[i].charAt(a);            
        } else if (tempScores[i].charAt(a) == ' ') {
            scores[scoreCount] = Integer.valueOf(tempNum);
            tempNum = "";
            scoreCount ++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`split(" ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) which takes a *regular expression*, `\\s+` matches one or more white space characters. Then you can use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) to ***parse*** the `String`(s) to `int`(s). Finally, you can use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) to display your `int[]`. Something like

```
String line = "1 2 3 4";
String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
int[] values = new int[tokens.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    values[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

Outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Would this still work if the numbers are more than one digit?

Comment: @JakeXia Yes. As long as the number is a valid `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very sure that the numbers will be separated by space then you could just use the split() method in String like below and parse individually :

```
String input = sc.nextLine(); (Use an sc.hasNextLine() check first)
if (input != null || !input.trim().isEmpty()) {
   String [] numStrings = input.split(" ");
   // convert the numbers as String to actually numbers by using 

Integer.parseInt(String num) method.
}
```